# How to implement un-install selected features in WiX

Tags: wix

I would like to ask about how to do when user launch un-install the product and able to select which features to be removed instead of whole application.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could Specify your this  under InstallExecuteSequence tag .

```
 <InstallExecuteSequence>
      <Custom Action="your component ID" After="Install sequence e.g. InstallFiles">NOT Installed</Custom>
    </InstallExecuteSequence>
```

You could use the below for your feature

```
   <Feature Id='WebSiteinstall' Title='Webinstall Features' Level='1'>NOT Installed </Feature>
```